# Find a sum of numbers in a given string

Tags: c

I have to find the sum of the numbers in a given string
For example for "a11b3" the amount will be refunded 14 because (11+3=14)
I wrote the following code but it does not work for me in any situation, how can I optimize it?

```
int SumStr(char* str)
{
    int i, sum = 0, digit = 0;
    while (*str)
    {
        digit = 0;
        while (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9' && *str)
        {
            digit = digit * 10 + (*str - '0');
            str++;
        }
        if (digit > 0)
            sum += digit;
        str++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Use the `isdigit()` C function to test each `char` as you loop through the string.

Comment: It does not work or does work? It works with the example you have given.

Comment: You can use the `strtol()` function in `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: What is `sum += digit`? What you expect? Imagine `digit` is 129. But this is 3 characters, not 129. BTW, digit and number are different things.

Comment: are you doing this on Windows. if so what ide are you using?

Comment: The code seems correct (other than you should move the check `... && *str` to the start of the statement, like `if (*str && *str >= '0' && *str <= '9')`, to make sure it short-circuits the evaluation in case it is null).

Can you provide a case where this function fails or givens the wrong result?

Comment: ) SumStr => Your Output is 50, Expected: 15 (-2)
1) SumStr => Your Output is 35, Expected: 34 (-2)
1) SumStr => Your Output is 125190, Expected: 15 (-2)
1) SumStr => Your Output is 125175, Expected: 3 (-2)
1) SumStr => Your Output is 125172, Expected: 1234 (-2)
1) SumStr => Your Output is 123938, Expected: 101 (-2)

Comment: in all thos cases the function not working well

Comment: @Eden Now "a11b3" is the answer 11 + 3 = 14 or 1+1+3 = 5 ??

Comment: if you have 2 digits one next to each other you need to think about it like a numbers so a11b3 it will be 11 +3 =14

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to do? Only add the numbers within any given array? Sorry, but i'm a tad confused as to what you actually try to accomplish with this code. For starters you are moving the pointer along within your inner while loop(access violations inc) and you overwrite your digit integer if there are more than 1 occurences one after the other(like in your example). I'm in a hurry, if the answer is still up when i get back in 1-2 hours I'll write a more detailed explanation of your problems/how to avoid em. Good luck for now.

Comment: @Eden are those answers bellow don't solve your problem or what?

Comment: yes the str++ in the end were the problem tnx all!

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the string with a pointer; when a digit is found the pointer can be passed to `strtol()` to convert the remaining part of the string to a number. The `strtol()` function accepts a pointer to the initial part of the string to be converted (a `char *`), and a pointer to a pointer used to store a pointer to the remaining portion of the string that could not be converted (a `char **`). This end pointer can be given the address of `str` in this case, so that after a number is converted, the search for digits resumes after the end of the converted number.

Note that `strtol()` returns a `long` value. The `sum_str()` function below returns a `long`. You could return an `int` instead if desired, yet if the final `sum` value were too large to fit into an `int` the value returned would be implementation dependent.

Some tests to detect overflow could be added in the summation loop (and this would be a good idea). No provision has been made (and there is no requirement provided) for negative numbers in the input string. Note that a simple change to allow for negative numbers in the input string would just involve testing for a `'-'` character followed by a digit:

```
    if (isdigit(*str) || (*str == '-' && isdigit(*(str + 1)))) {
            sum += strtol(str, &str, 10);
```

The input string should probably be validated before giving it to the function. Should strings with no digits be allowed? Should strings with more than one character between numbers be allowed? Should strings with a terminal non-digit be allowed? Should strings with decimal points be allowed? The answers to these questions would allow the `sum_str()` function and the code that calls it to be refined. In the code below strings containing no digits return a sum of zero, groups of one or more non-digit characters, including decimal points, serve to separate the digits to be summed, and terminal characters are ignored after the final digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

long sum_str(char *str);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%ld\n", sum_str("a11b3c-4"));

    return 0;
}

long sum_str(char *str)
{
    long sum = 0;

    while(*str) {
        if (isdigit(*str)) {
                sum += strtol(str, &str, 10);
            }
        if (*str) {              // don't increment if end of string reached
            ++str;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Program output:

```
14
```

Answer (score 1):

*How can I optimize it?*.  I am not sure how the following will optimize in terms of speed or memory size, but it does make the code a little simpler, and more readable:

The following uses the `isdigit()` function and *[ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/)* to count numbers:

```
int main(void)
{
    char buf[] = {"abc23jrt5"};//sum of integers: 23 + 5 = 28
    int count = int SumStr(buf);

    return 0;   
}

//Edited to sum instances of numbers embedded in string.
//adjacent digits such as `11` in the string `avf11e5` are treated
//as the integer value `11`, not `1 + 1`.
int SumStr(char *buf)
{
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while( *buf != 0 )
    {
        i = 0;
        while(isdigit(*buf))
        {
            i *= 10, i += *buf - '0';
            if(*buf != 0) buf++;
        }
        sum += i;
        if(*buf != 0) buf++;
    }
    return sum;
};
```

Comment: you need to change the name of the function countNumbers to SumStr

Comment: Its returns sum of 10 i need it return 23+5=28

Comment: @Eden - Once that became clear in the comments, it would be useful that you add that specification into your post.  The answer is edited.

Answer (score 0):

You do one more `str++` than you should.

```
int SumStr(const char *str) {                        // added const
    int sum = 0, digit = 0;                          // removed i
    while (*str) {
        digit = 0;
        while (*str && *str >= '0' && *str <= '9') { // swapped order of conditions
            digit = digit * 10 + (*str - '0');
            str++;
        }
        if (digit > 0) sum += digit;
        else str++;                                  // added else
    }
    return sum;
}
```

see https://ideone.com/Aerrh5